# Matplotlib updating axis

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, ipython

I'm looking for method that will allow me to update axis when my script is running but, I couldn't find it. For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = (1,2)
y = (1,2)

plt.plot(x,y, 'r-')
plt.show()

#here during run of program I want to clear axis with help of plt.cla() and update it 
#new one

# x = (2,4)
# y = (2,4)
#plt.plot(x,y, 'b-')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the functionality you want you probably want to set matplotlib to interactive mode:

```
plt.ion()
```

Then call draw to update. For example:

```
import numpy
import time
x = (1,2)
y = (1,2)
plt.ion()
plt.plot(x,y, 'r-')
plt.draw()

for i in range(100):
   print i
   time.sleep(1)
   plt.cla()
   y = (numpy.random.normal(), numpy.random.normal())
   plt.plot(x,y, 'r-')
   plt.draw()
```